# Youtube API v3, Display Viewcount from single video

Tags: php, api, view, youtube, count

Hey Im trying to display video views from a single youtube video using the Youtube API v3,

Using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=MYKEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&alt=json

This is the result i get back. 
check the jsfiddle link

https:// jsfiddle.net/ou5vopqt/

Now to the part i cant handle, how to display the viewcount, using php i guess?
Would love if somebody could help me out.

```
<?php 
$video_ID = "SyphzxruFeo";
$jsonURL = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$video_ID}&key=MYkey&part=statistics");
$json = json_decode($jsonURL);
$views = $json->{'items'}[0]->{'statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo number_format($views,0,'.',',');
 ?>
```

this worked. thanks

Comment: Where is your code? Show us what you have tried and ask about where you have problem.

Comment: been trying this

<?php
$video_ID = '7lCDEYXw3mM';
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=MYKEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'items'}->{'statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views;
?>

Comment: you need to parse json output and then get the required variable, look at PHP manual: [PHP manual - json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @AnderssonJohn Edit your question, put the code there and tell us, what is the output, errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

i have create this function to retrieve ViewsCount, this is working for Youtube Api v3

```
public function youtube_views($url)
{
    $api_key = "Your_Api_for_youtube";
    parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
    $video_ID = $my_array_of_vars['v']; 

    $url_content = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$video_ID}&key={$api_key}&part=statistics";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_content);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
      echo curl_error($ch);
      echo "\n<br />";
      $contents = '';
    } 
    else 
    {
      curl_close($ch);
    }

    if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
    echo "Failed to get contents.";
    $contents = '';
    }

    $JSON_Data = json_decode($contents);
    return $JSON_Data->{'items'}[0]->{'statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
}
```

for example to use the function

```
youtube_views("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cwZGYYPgZM");
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more context to help you, but as a general answer to a general question, I would point you to read about JSON and jQuery.

Check this link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Without a proper context, I can't help you further.